# how to configure tikiwiki featured profile

Tags: wiki, tiki-wiki

I have installed the Tikiwiki 11.0 in my system. After successful installation , site show the below 3 steps. ( 1. Login with the new password, 2. Enable tiki features 3. Run tiki profile.

I have logged as admin, and trying to configure the site for collabrative community ( like wiki pedia website). Please guide me how to configure the base engine like wiki.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply the collaborative community profile, log in as the admin.  On the front screen of the Tiki site, about half way down, there should be a section called "Featured Profiles".  The first featured profile is collaborative community.  Click on the link that says "apply profile now".  This will take you to the profile repository section of the admin page.

Find your version of Tiki from the list on the right side of the screen, and double click on it.  Then click the list button.  You should see a list of options.  Look for Collaborative_Community_11x.  Click on the name.  This will load the code for the profile, and this will also let you type a couple options like the site name.  Once you have everything entered, click the "Apply Now" button, and it will apply the profile.